# razorview conditional with jquery model field

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have some jquery like this...

```
init: function () {
        var self = this;

        this.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: $.url.action(self.controller, self.action, { projectId: projectId }),
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "StudyId",
                    fields: {
                        Name: { type: "string" },
                        ViewName: { type: "string" },
                        Description: { type: "string" },
                        ViewDescription: { type: "string" },
                        UpdateDate: { type: "date" },
                        StudyId: { type: "number" },
                        NextMilestoneName: { type: "string" },
                        NextMilestoneDate: { type: "date" },
                        StudyStatus: { type: "string"}
                    }
                }
            },
            sort: { field: "UpdateDate", dir: "desc" },
            sortable: { mode: "single", allowUnsort: false },
            pageSize: 4
        });
```

I want to conditionally display this depending on if ViewDescription is empty...

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(????))
{
    <span><strong>@Resources.Resources.Description1 </strong>#:ViewDescription#</span>
     <br>
}
```

I can't figure it out! what do i put into the ????'s to access the ViewDescription?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you posted, it seems that you are trying to leverage a razor view based on information that wont exist until after the page loads, even until that Kendo control call "Read()". That Razor view will be built before that javascript has executed. However, after that code executes, you can do something like this in JS.
(Also check here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#events-change)

init: function () {
        var self = this;

```
    this.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: $.url.action(self.controller, self.action, { projectId: projectId }),
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        change: function(e) {
         if(e.items["ViewDescription"]!=null){
             $("#IDofDivHere").append("<span><strong>@Resources.Resources.Description1</strong>"+e.items["ViewDescription"]+"</span><br>");
         }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "StudyId",
                fields: {
                    Name: { type: "string" },
                    ViewName: { type: "string" },
                    Description: { type: "string" },
                    ViewDescription: { type: "string" },
                    UpdateDate: { type: "date" },
                    StudyId: { type: "number" },
                    NextMilestoneName: { type: "string" },
                    NextMilestoneDate: { type: "date" },
                    StudyStatus: { type: "string"}
                }
            }
        },
        sort: { field: "UpdateDate", dir: "desc" },
        sortable: { mode: "single", allowUnsort: false },
        pageSize: 4
    });
```

So we are wiring up the kendo event change that should get fired when the data is retrieved (like a success callback in ajax), and then appending the data you wanted wherever you want it to go